# Synchronize iCalendar Events like theSkimm

Tags: icalendar

My use case is similar to what [theSkimm](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/theskimm/id1034995058) app does which is as follows:

1. To push events to iCalendar app on iPhone once user opts for Calendar Synchronization in the mobile application (once user subscribes to the calendar).
2. To delete events pushed by the application to iCalendar app once opts out Calendar Synchronization in the application
3. If the user subscribes to Calendar Synchronization, each event pushed to the application should have a link to unsubscribe for the event. By clicking the link the event in iCalendar should disappear.

1st use case can be achieved when the user clicks subscribe -> App can fetch events from server and push it into iCalendar using EventKit.

2nd use case can be achieved when user clicks unsubscribe -> App can fetch all events from server that were pushed to iCalendar earlier.

3rd use case is where it is getting a bit tricky to understand the workflow as there is no API provided by apple that I could find online which helps me move into user's iCalendar and delete the requested event.

I request anyone having any idea regarding this or any previous work experience to please help me our guide me in how can things be done.